# SwiftUI: View not expanding in height inside ScrollView

Tags: swiftui, scrollview

I'm encountering an issue with a SwiftUI view called EventView not expanding in height when placed inside a ScrollView. Here's the code snippet for the EventView:

```
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            HStack {
                Image("some image")
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                VStack {
                    TextView(text: event.title, style: .footNote)
                    TextView(text: event.subject, style: .footNote)
                }
            }
 
        }
        .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8))
        .padding(.vertical)
        .frame(maxWidth: 300)
    }
```

No matter how much text is inside either of TextView - this view will grow in height indefinitely. This is the behavior that I want (the TextView is a custom wrapper over the Text view, nothing serious is going on there except for setting font and style).

However, when the EventView is placed inside a ScrollView, it fails to increase in height as expected.

```
  var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: .zero) {
            HStack {
                TextView(text: getTitle(), style: .title)
                Spacer()
            }
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                HStack {
                    ForEach(events) { event in
                        EventView(event: event)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I've tried using the .fixedSize() modifier, but it does not seem to resolve the issue.

Could someone please assist me in finding a solution to make the EventView grow in height within the ScrollView, similar to how it behaves when it's not embedded inside the ScrollView? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: This needs a [mre].